# How to "Float" a label on a TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, label

Can you "Float" a `Label` on a `TabControl` like this:
[image: Float]

Like that "About" `Label` on the right of the picture or the "Minimize to Tray" `CheckBox`?

Comment: whoops, sorry, force of habit!

Comment: If using the designer, then place the label above the TabControl, then use your arrow keys to move it into place.  Set the anchor properties appropriately.  If it falls behind the TabControl, right click it and select BringToFront.

Comment: You should have done that as an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the designer, then place the label above the TabControl, then use your arrow keys to move it into place. Set the anchor properties appropriately. If it falls behind the TabControl, right click it and select BringToFront.

If the Label is inside the TabControl, you can use the "View" - "Other Windows" - "Document Outline" panel to control the hierarchy of the child controls.